# Скрыть элементы, если открыта определенная страница

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно что бы на определенной странице был скрыт элемент, который отображается на остальных. Как написать условие на js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
var this_url = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host) + window.location.pathname;

// alert(this_url); // для тестирования

if (this_url == 'адрес')
{
    // дальше ваш код скрытия блока ...

}
```